# NumPy: Improperly Creating 2-D Array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reading in data and trying to create a NumPy array of shape (194, 1).  So it should look like: `[[4], [0], [9], ...]`

I'm doing this:

```
def parse_data(file_name):
    data = []
    target = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            temp = line.split()
            x = [float(x) for x in temp[:2]]
            y = float(temp[2])
            data.append(np.array(x))
            target.append(np.array(y))
    return np.array(data), np.array(target)

x, y = parse_data("data.txt")
```

when I inspect `y.shape`, it's `(194,)`, not `(194,1)` as I expected.

The `x` has shape `(194,2)` as I'd expect, however.

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some lines from `data.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have expected `np.array(y)` to automatically turn your scalar `y` into a 1-element row. That's not how NumPy works.

`np.array(y)` is *0-dimensional*. Putting a bunch of those in a list and calling `array` on the list produces a 1-dimensional result, not a 2-dimensional one.

Answer (score 1):

When `np.array()` is called on a list of numpy arrays built from scalars it concatenates them and then creates a numpy array, giving you your (194,) shape.

You can always reshape y to your desired shape:

```
def parse_data(file_name):
    data = []
    target = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            temp = line.split()
            x = [float(x) for x in temp[:2]]
            y = float(temp[2])
            data.append(np.array(x))
            target.append(y)
    return np.array(data), np.array(target).reshape(-1, 1)

x, y = parse_data("data.txt")
```

Of course you can also fix your problem with:

```
target.append(np.array([y]))
```

An example of the behavior I stated above:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(5)
b = np.array(4)
v = [a, b]
v
>>>[array(5), array(4)]
np.array(v)
>>>array(5, 4) #arrays are concatenated
```

Comment: `return np.array(data), np.array(target).reshape(-1, 1)` likely to be better, in case the amount of data varies.

Comment: I think it should be (-1, 1), not (1, -1).

Comment: You could also use  `return np.array(data), np.vstack(target)`
A bit more concise and works as long as target is 1D.

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the `np.array` in the iteration.

```
def parse_data(file_name):
    data = []
    target = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            temp = line.split()
            x = [float(x) for x in temp[:2]]
            y = float(temp[2])
            data.append(x)
            target.append(y)
    return np.array(data), np.array(target)
```

This would create `data` like:

```
 [[1.0, 2.0],[3.0, 4.0], ....]
```

and `target` like

```
 [1.2, 3.2, 3.1, ...]
```

`np.array(data)` then turns the list of lists into a 2d array, and the list of numbers into a 1d array.

It is then easy to reshape or add a dimension to the 1d, making it (1,n) or (n,1) or what ever you need.

Remember the basic array construction methods are:

```
np.array([1,2,3])             # 1d
np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])       # 2d
```